# Google Wave - Adding a participant to a Wave with the Python API

Tags: python, google-wave

How do I add a participant to a Wave using the Python API given their email address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method to add a participant given a user id (AddParticipant) to waves is in the [waveapi.model.OpBasedWavelet subclass](http://wave-robot-python-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pydocs/index.html), rather than just waveapi.model.Wavelet. This user id is an email address. Look at [this sample](http://wave-robot-python-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pydocs/index.html).